# C# accelerator keys not working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working on an application that has multiple dockable panels like Visual Studio. At some point the accelerator keys for the menu stopped working. They sometimes work depending on what panel is currently active. When they are not working pressing the alt key sets the focus to the menu bar and shows the underscores under the appropriate characters, but pressing any of the characters does not show the menu.

I've been banging my head against this for a little bit and am wondering if there is an easier way to find out what is happening to those key presses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there was a control that had overridden Control.ProcessMnemonic(). There was a logic error that was returning true when it should have been returning false.

Not exactly an easy error to find without spending a lot if time.

Answer (score 0):

The first place to look is in any key press handlers within your code.  I would set a breakpoint in all of those and see if those event handlers are stopping the key press from being bubbled up.